# Select groups of users if one or more user made a comment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following `table1`

```
user   group   comment
----------------------
 1     a       foo
 2     a
 3     a
 4     b       bar
 5     c
 6     c
 7     d
 8     d
 9     d
10     d
11     e       bax
12     e       baz
```

I need to make 2 queries, each of which returns groups:

- query 1: groups of which at least 1 user has made a comment
- query 2: groups of which no user has made a comment

result of query 1:

```
user   group   comment
----------------------
 1     a       foo
 2     a
 3     a
 4     b       bar
11     e       bax
12     e       baz
```

result of query 2:

```
user   group   comment
----------------------
 5     c
 6     c
 7     d
 8     d
 9     d
```

I tried the following but then I saw some of the same `user`s in both groups:

```
select  * 
from    [table1] t1
where   t1.[group] in (
    select distinct [group] from [table] where [comment] <> ''
)
order by t1.[user] asc

select  * 
from    [table1] t1
where   t1.[group] in (
    select distinct [group] from [table] where [comment] = ''
)
order by t1.[user] asc
```

I then realised this is because in the same group, comment can be either set (`comment <> ''`) AND not set (`comment = ''`) but I don't know how to solve this in my queries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

This gives you the users of groups in which comments have been posted.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.group = t.group and t1.comment is not null
)
```

To get the users of groups without any comment, you can just turn `exists` to `not exists`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`.  For groups with a comment:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table1 tt1
              where tt1.group = t1.group and
                    tt1.comment is not null
             );
```

Use `not exists` for the other set of rows.